# Find conditions for $A$ and $B$ in which the intersection $A∩B$ contain infinitely many points

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ two sets. Assuming that the intersection $A∩B$ contain at least one element.

**My question** is: Find conditions for $A$ and $B$ in which the intersection $A∩B$ contain infinitely many points. I have no idea to start.

Comment: Some more context would be in order. Otherwise, the generic answer is that the necessary and sufficient condition for $A \cap B$ to have infinitely many elements is that $A \cap B$ *does* have infinitely many elements.

Comment: How about: For every natural number $n$, $A \cap B$ contains at least $n$ elements.

Comment: @dxiv: Ok I remove it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: But this add some complications to the answer.

Comment: Is there more context? Do we know _anything_ about $A$ and $B$ other than that they are sets?

Comment: @AlexisOlson: Yes, we know only that $A$ and $B$ are  non empty sets

Comment: @E.James It's unclear what you are asking. If $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary sets and all you know is that $A \cap B$ is not empty, there is no magic condition to distinguish between $A \cap B$ being finite vs. infinite. Your question begins with `assuming that` - you should really post what follows after that in the *real* problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A necessary condition is that both $A$ and $B$ contain infinitely many points. This is clearly not sufficient though as they could be disjoint or only share a finite number of points.

Any necessary and sufficient condition for *arbitrary* sets $A$ and $B$ is going to be equivalent to your original requirement that $A \cap B$ has infinitely many elements.

If you knew something more about the sets $A$ and $B$ (for example, if $A$ and $B$ are open sets in the standard Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$) then you might be able to find some non-trivial conditions.